# Loading Rust Code in Java, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

Tags: java, dll, rust, java-native-interface

I have been learning rust over the past few weeks, and I think I reached a level of comfort with the language. For one of my personal projects, I'm having trouble calling rust code(compiled into a dll) from java.

Here is what I have currently for the rust code:

```rust
use std::f64;
use std::any::Any;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn _Java_getDifferenceInAngleDegrees(env: *const (), jclass: *const (),from: f64, to: f64) -> f64 {
    let mut angle = to - from;
    // Naive algorithm
    while (angle >= 180.0) {
        angle -= 360.0;
    }
    while (angle < -180.0) {
        angle += 360.0;
    }
    angle
}

fn main() {
    println!("a");
}
```

And here is how I try to load it in java

```java
import java.io.File;

public class test{
    public static native double getDifferenceInAngleDegrees(double from, double to);        

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File("rustMath.dll");
        System.load(f.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(test.getDifferenceInAngleDegrees(120.0, 119.0));
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: test.getDifferenceInAngleDegrees(DD)D
        at test.getDifferenceInAngleDegrees(Native Method)
        at test.main(test.java:17)
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "rustMath"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["22ethompson"]
edition = "2018"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
path = "src/main.rs"

[profile.release]
lto = true

[dependencies]
jni = "0.10.2"
```

Comment: I reduced the code, because you only call `getDifferenceInAngleDegrees` so the rest is not needed here. Please comment or rollback if you feel different.

Comment: It looks like your Rust functions are missing the Java class name. That is, `_Java_test_getDifferenceInAngleDegrees` etc.

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.rs/jni/0.12.0/jni/ ?

Comment: @hellow: Native functions referenced from Java need to be named in a specific manner: _"A native method name is concatenated from the following components:

* the prefix Java\_
* a mangled fully-qualified class name
* an underscore (“\_”) separator
* a mangled method name
* for overloaded native methods, two underscores (“\_\_”) followed by the mangled argument signature"_

Comment: How do you compile the Rust code? If you call `rustc` directly, can you show your command-line? If instead you use cargo, can you show your `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: @hellow Hey, I've tried all of the suggestions, but none of them seem to work. I'm just compiling this through cargo build --release, and the cargo.toml contents was edited into the post. If you have any more suggestions, or have a specific plan in mind for implementation, that would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Try to run you app with `LD_DEBUG=all` or `LD_DEBUG=symbols` environmet variable. If the LD_DEBUG variable is set then the Linux dynamic linker will dump debug information which can be used to resolve most loading problems very quickly. (but linux only...)

Comment: As Michael mentioned, the native method name in native must have a certain format (no leading underscore as in the code currently). 

Have you tried using the javac to produce a C header file with a proper signature: `javac -h . test.java`? You can just copy the method name from it.

Comment: Also see the example in the library repository: https://github.com/jni-rs/jni-rs/blob/v0.12.1/example/mylib/src/lib.rs#L26